# Volunteer Report DB Error: unknown error

Tags: civireport

When trying to have a volunteer report there is this error in WP+CiviCRM
The error logs are:

From logviewer

```
[debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
[error]
[debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(954): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
[error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
```

From CiviCRM Report Error by email extension

```
***ERROR***
message:            DB Error: unknown error
code:               
exception:          PEAR_Exception Object
(
    [cause:protected] => DB_Error Object
        (
            [error_message_prefix] =>
            [mode] => 16
            [level] => 1024
            [code] => -1
            [message] => DB Error: unknown error
            [userinfo] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS project_civireport.title as project_project, civicrm_contact_assignee_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_contact_assignee, activity_civireport.id as civicrm_activity_id, activity_civireport.source_record_id as civicrm_activity_source_record_id, activity_civireport.activity_type_id as civicrm_activity_activity_type_id, activity_civireport.subject as civicrm_activity_activity_subject, activity_civireport.activity_date_time as civicrm_activity_activity_date_time, activity_civireport.status_id as civicrm_activity_status_id, activity_assignment_civireport.contact_id as civicrm_activity_assignment_contact_id, activity_target_civireport.contact_id as civicrm_activity_target_contact_id,
activity_source_civireport.contact_id as civicrm_activity_source_contact_id, cg.volunteer_role_id_1 as role_role, cg.time_scheduled_in_minutes_2 as time_scheduled_time_scheduled, cg.time_completed_in_minutes_3 as time_completed_time_completed, case_activity_civireport.case_id as civicrm_case_activity_case_id , civicrm_contact_assignee_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_sort_name 
        FROM civicrm_activity activity_civireport
             LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity_contact  activity_target_civireport
                    ON activity_civireport.id = activity_target_civireport.activity_id AND
                       activity_target_civireport.record_type_id = 3
             LEFT JOIN civicrm_value_civivolunteer_ cg
                    ON activity_civireport.id = cg.entity_id
             LEFT JOIN civicrm_volunteer_need n
                    ON n.id = cg.volunteer_need_id_
             LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value ov_civireport ON ( ov_civireport.value = cg.volunteer_role_id_1 AND ov_civirep...

***LAST ERROR***
Array
(
    [type] => 16384
    [message] => Calling the "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface::dispatch()" method with the event name as the first argument is deprecated since Symfony 4.3, pass it as the second argument and provide the event object as the first argument instead.
    [file] => /home/adraitalia/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php
    [line] => 58
)

And this 

***BACKTRACE***
#0 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/CRM/ReportError/Utils.php(31): reporterror_civicrm_generatereport("xxxx", (Array:3), NULL, (Array:0))
#1 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/CRM/ReportError/Handler/FormsNoReferer.php(58): CRM_ReportError_Utils::sendReport((Array:3), (Array:0))
#2 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/reporterror.php(149): CRM_ReportError_Handler_FormsNoReferer::handler((Array:3), (Array:0))
#3 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(429): reporterror_civicrm_handler((Array:3))
#4 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(PEAR_Exception))
#5 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#6 /home/xxxx/xxxxl/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#7 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#8 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#9 /home/xxxx/xxxx/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#10 {main}
```

Thank you for help

Comment: can you add full sql code, it might have actual reason of DB: unknown error.

Comment: Custom field configuration for civivolunteer has become corrupted in some way. You can see it because in the query it says e.g. `civicrm_value_civivolunteer_` which should have the full table name but is missing the last bit.